# Спарсить Javascript с сайта

Tags: curl, php, синтаксический-анализ, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как спарсить js-код с сайта? Точнее я даже строку кода знаю, но как спарсить - нет.

Comment: спарсить, в смысле скачать js файл и найти в нем определенный кусок кода (текста)?

Comment: @KoVadim найти в нем определенный кусок кода, а если точнее то его ссылку, там строка вида document.location.href='', то что в кавычках надо спарсить.

Comment: Получаешь в переменную контент и парсишь с помощью регулярных выражений.
$url = preg_replace("/.+document\.location\.href=\"(.+?)\".+/", "$1", $content); Код не проверял, но примерно так. Хорошо бы увидеть точный фрагмент js кода, где фигурирует ссылка.

Comment: @Nik555 не работает :(

Comment: @Lektor, приведите фрагмент js кода, чтобы я смог точно написать рег. выражение.

Comment: @Nik555 http://jsfiddle.net/G8h2T/ здесь код, нужно выдрать значение из document.location.href

Comment: спарсером же, что за вопросы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$s = file_get_contents("http://"); // ссылка на js файл
$m = array();
preg_match_all("/document\.location\.href='(.+?)'/", $s, $m);
$url = $m[1][0]; // $url содержит ссылку
?>
```

Comment: @Nik555 работает, спасибо!